# HDFS + create simbolic link between HDFS folder to local filesystem folder

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I searched in google but not find it,

is it possible to create link between HDFS folder to local folder?

example

we want to create link between **folder_1** in HDFS to **/home/hdfs_mirror** local folder

HDFS folder:

```
su hdfs
$ hdfs dfs -ls /hdfs_home/folder_1
```

Linux local folder:

```
ls /home/hdfs_mirror
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible.

This is because we are talking about two different File Systems (HDFS and Local FileSystem).

in case we want to keep syncing the Local Data Directory to HDFS directory then need to make use of some tools like Apache Flume.